# how to remove \r\n\r\n from an textarea using php

Tags: php

I am not able to remove these "\r\n\r\n" from textarea using any of below method

```
Good job overall!\r\n\r\n*********************************************************************** \r\n\r\nSoft skills: Please don\'t forget to ask customers for the reason of cancellation.
```

[image]

```
methods 
$resolution = trim($resolution);

//Effort 2
$resolution = nl2br($resolution);

//Effort 3
$resolution = htmlentities($resolution);

//Effort 4
$resolution = preg_replace("\\r\\n","<br>",$resolution);

$snip = str_replace("\t", '', $snip); // remove tabs
$snip = str_replace("\n", '', $snip); // remove new lines
$snip = str_replace("\r", '', $snip); // remove carriage returns

Array
```

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 5497
            [type] => F
            [parent_id] => 0
            [field_type] => selectbox
            [field_name] => Retention Offered?
            [required] => 1
            [maxlength] => 0
            [field_value] => YES
            [not_applicable] => on
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [field_id] => 5494
        [type] => F
        [parent_id] => 0
        [field_type] => textarea
        [field_name] => Summary of Interaction
        [required] => 1
        [maxlength] => 0
        [field_value] => Cx requested cancel, agent secured and explained account, offered rates, cx declined, agent confirmed cancellation
        [not_applicable] => on
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [field_id] => 5495
        [type] => F
        [parent_id] => 0
        [field_type] => textarea
        [field_name] => Feedback
        [required] => 0
        [maxlength] => 0
        [field_value] => Good job overall!\r\n\r\n*********************************************************************** \r\n\r\nSoft skills: Please don\'t forget to ask customers for the reason of cancellation.
        [not_applicable] => on
    )
```

)

Comment: The last method is correct, except that you need to replace, for example, `\\n` (with two backslashes) with newlines `\n`.

Comment: Where do you get the string from that contains `'\t'`? Should't the original string be `' '`?

Comment: @RolandStarke from the database array , please check updated question

Comment: Couldn't you save (in the database) the original line breaks and tabs instead of saving '\r\n\t'? Then you don't need to worry about it afterwards.

Comment: @RolandStarke values are submitted by client

Comment: And you don't control the clients code? (sry for "stupid" questions, just trying to help). When filling out a textarea und using linebreaks you usually don't end up with '\r\n' in php only if the user typed that in literally.

Comment: @RolandStarke  we have used serialize() to serialize data , is there any way to force data in double quotes

Comment: If you serialize something you need to unserialize it later to get the value back. Could i ask why you need the data in double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

user [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), To remove **\n\r** from a string, follow the below code

```
$title = "Good job overall!\r\n\r\n*********************************************************************** \r\n\r\nSoft skills: Please don't forget to ask customers for the reason of cancellation";
$new_title = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$title); 
echo $new_title;
```

**[DOME](https://3v4l.org/WJB53)**

Comment: values are coming from database in array

Answer (score 0):

I done this using below code , ( '\t', '\n', '\r' ) just used single quotes instead of double quotes

```
$snip = str_replace('\t', '', $snip); // remove tabs
$snip = str_replace('\n', '', $snip); // remove new lines
$snip = str_replace('\r', '', $snip); // remove carriage returns
```